# Creating a regex for parsing screens resolutions

Tags: php

I have a string of text that somewhere will contain the resolution to my vid in the format `###x###` or `####x####` (ex. 320x240 or ex. 1024x1280 ex. 320x1024 etc.) or any combo in between. I am not great at regexes yet and I was wondering if anyone could point out where I am going wrong.

```
$res='some long string';
$search='/([0-9]{3-4})x([0-9]{3-4})/';
preg_match($search, $res, $matches);
$res1=$matches[1];
$res2=$matches[2];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be:

```
$search='/([0-9]{3,4})x([0-9]{3,4})/';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
$search='/([1-9]\d{2,3})x([1-9]\d{2,3})/';
```

(more specific)

Comment: First character of height or width cannot be `0`; I also used `\d` instead of `[0-9]`.